# SVM: scaled dataset gives worse results?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have a **multiclass classification** problem. My dataset (let's call data `X` and labels - `y`) represents sets of points on 640x480 images, so all elements in `X` are integers in range of valid pixels. I'm trying to use SVM for this problem. If I run SVM against dataset **as is**, it gives accuracy of **74%**. However, if I **scale** data to range `[0..1]`, it gives much poorer results - only **69%** of correct results.

I double checked histogram of elements in `X` and its scaled version `Xs`, and they are identical. So data is not corrupted, just normalized. Knowing ideas behind SVM I assumed scaling should not affect results, but it does. So why does it happen?

---

Here's my code in case I made mistake in it:

```
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> 
>>> X, y = ...
>>> Xs = X.astype(np.float32) / (X.max() - X.min())    
>>> cross_val_score(SVC(kernel='linear'), X, y, cv=10).mean()
0.74531073446327667
>>> cross_val_score(SVC(kernel='linear'), Xs, y, cv=10).mean()
0.69485875706214695
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling should certainly affect results, but it should improve them. However, the performance of an SVM is critically dependent on its `C` setting, which trades off the cost of misclassification on the training set vs. model simplicity, and which should be determined using e.g. [grid search and nested cross-validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/grid_search_digits.html#example-grid-search-digits-py). The default settings are very rarely optimal for any given problem.

Comment: But why does scaling affect results? If SVM simply builds hyperplane, then, in my understanding, after scaling params of this hyperplance should also just be scaled. For me it sounds like scaling just changes unit length and doesn't really change inherent structure, which is essential for SVM. Does it?

Comment: @ffriend The SVM solution is regularized, and the regularization makes it scale-dependent.